# Running two function together only if first function is running first with Multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to 2 function to run together however first func1() should run and func1() should call func2() then both the function should run simultaneously till all the condition are met.
here is the dummy code

```
x=1
def func1():
    global x
    while x>0:
       a=input()
       do something
       func2()              #calling func2() only once


def func2():
    global x
    while 1:
       if x==5:
          x=0              #x become 0 so now while loop for func1 should end
          break
      x+=1
```

Here is my code that i try to run with multiprocessing.

```
import datetime
from time import sleep
from threading import *
from multiprocessing import Process
import sys

bot_reply_time = 0
x = 1
def func1():
    y = 0
    global bot_reply_time
    while x > 0:
        a = input("Q>")                          #EOF error here when reading a line
        print("Bot replay: Hi")
        c = datetime.datetime.now()
        bot_reply_time = (c.hour * 60 * 60) + (c.minute * 60) + c.second
        if y == 0:
            y += 1
            p2 = Process(target=func2)          #calling func2 only once
            p2.start()
def func2():
    global x
    global bot_reply_time
    while True:
        last_bot_reply_time = bot_reply_time
        c = datetime.datetime.now()
        current_time = (c.hour * 60 * 60) + (c.minute * 60) + c.second
        if (bot_reply_time + 10 == current_time and bot_reply_time == last_bot_reply_time):
            x = 0                           #x become 0 so now while loop for func1 should end
            print("session expired")
            break


if __name__=='__main__':
    p1 = Process(target = func1)
    p1.start()
```

However i am getting error as "EOF when reading a line". I dont get error if i remove "input()"

Comment: I think you meant 'Idle' and not Ideal..

Comment: What is the error you are getting? We can't really help if we don't know the issue you are having.

Comment: i am getting error as EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: yes correct David. Tanks for correcting me

Comment: Using global shared variables like that isn't thread-safe. Use [locks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects) instead.

Answer (score 0):

here i have a little example how to use signals to set timeout in fuunctions:

```
import signal
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def timeout(time):
    # Register a function to raise a TimeoutError on the signal.
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, raise_timeout)
    # Schedule the signal to be sent after ``time``.
    signal.alarm(time)

    try:
        yield
    except TimeoutError:
        pass
    finally:
        # Unregister the signal so it won't be triggered
        # if the timeout is not reached.
        signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, signal.SIG_IGN)


def raise_timeout(signum, frame):
    raise TimeoutError


def my_func():
    # Add a timeout block.
    with timeout(1):
        print('entering block')
        import time
        time.sleep(10)
        print('This should never get printed because the line before timed out')
```

i hope it helps but if you wana a easer way just use `func-timeout` python module.

```
https://pypi.org/project/func-timeout/
```